# Creating and Naming Pandas DataFrames automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, naming

I'm sure there must be a simple way of doing this. I have a loop that opens all files in the folder with `time` in the title, and I want to be able to open each one as a DataFrame with the name of the file that I opened as the title of the DataFrame. Currently, the only way I know of naming a `DataFrame` is creating it `(i.e. inf1 = pd.read_csv(fname))` and obviously `inf1` is not a spectacularly useful name, plus each time the loop runs inf1 is overwritten.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you create a dictionary? i.e. `dct[fname] = pd.read_csv(fname)`

Comment: I'm assuming I just don't understand dictionaries then, as I've only seen them created manually and I need it to be automatic, as I don't know the amount or names of the variables beforehand. I was hoping there was something simple I could do with a list, or just rename the DataFrame afterwards using fname, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Note: having looked at dictionaries and totally failed to understand them, a simple way round this is just to do whatever you need to the files and save them as csv at the end again, as in inf1.to_csv(fname + ' reindexed.csv').